# Render response of button click

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a class which renders 2 different buttons. When I press a button, an API call gets triggered and I print the response of that API call to the console. However, what I actually want is to render the response of the API call. How can I achieve this?

```
 class Form extends Component {
  handleClick = async event => {
    switch (event.target.id) {
      case "createSalesOrder":
        {
          let res = await axios.post("http://localhost:5000/", {
            buttonClicked: "createSalesOrder",

          });
          console.log(res.data);
          break;
        }

      case "delete":
        {
          let res = await axios.delete("http://localhost:5000/delete");
           console.log(res.data);
          break;
        }

      default:
        console.log("click didnt work");
    }

  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className='form'>
         <h3>Delete all sales orders from SAP Sales Cloud which this webservice created</h3>
          <Button variant="success"  onClick={this.handleClick} id="createSalesOrder" >Create Sales Order</Button>
          <br />
          <br />
          <Button variant="danger" onClick={this.handleClick} id="delete" >Delete Sales Order</Button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Use a stateful component. Print a state value, and set this state value when button is clicked

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-ajax.html

Comment: @Quentin he wants to call after click

Comment: @T00rk — Principles are the same, and they already have click handler code.